# Create panel for each row in database and style column elements differently

Tags: html, mysql, css, asp.net

I'm creating a website that'll contain a news section. The news will be uploaded to a database from which i will present the data to the users. The news table consists of the columns `ID`, `Title`, `Data` and `Date`.

Currently I've succeeded up to the point of showing the data in the columns `Title` and `Data` as they are the ones I'm interested in showing. But each row are to be presented by themselves as a header and information where the header has its own css style and the information another. And then i want the next row to show up next to it. With this code it just put the titles in one panel and the corresponding information in another. I want them to be their own panels with their own styles.

This is my code this far in Index.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "----------------------";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM News;", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

        int i = 1;
        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label lblTitle = new Label();
                lblTitle.ID = "title" + i;
                lblTitle.Text = reader.GetString(1);

                Label lblData = new Label();
                lblData.ID = "data" + i;
                lblData.Text = reader.GetString(2);

                panelTitle.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
                panelTitle.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
                panelData.Controls.Add(lblData);
                panelData.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>")); 

                i++;
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

also this piece of code in Index.aspx:

```
            <div id="nTextHeader">
                <asp:Panel ID="panelTitle" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                <div id="nTextCont">
                    <asp:Panel ID="panelData" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As I said this just puts the data in two different panels which makes it easy to style them correctly. But it also puts all the data in the same place, which is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider stop using windows UI controllers such as `panels` and stuff, and start using manual output options via `Response.Write( <html data here> );` unless you're making forms, then a MVC structure might come in handy.

Here's something along the lines you need in `index.aspx`:

```
<div id="nTextHeader">
    <asp:Panel ID="newsPanel" runat="server">

    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

And for your `.NET` code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "----------------------";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM News;", con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

    int i = 1;
    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Panel pan = new Panel(); 

            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.ID = "title" + i;
            lblTitle.Text = reader.GetString(1);
            pan.Controls.add(lblTitle);

            Label lblData = new Label();
            lblData.ID = "data" + i;
            lblData.Text = reader.GetString(2);
            pan.Controls.add(lblData);

            newsPanel.Controls.add(pan);

            i++;
        }
        reader.NextResult();
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

### Using static HTML elements (a "better" solution)

A "better" solution would be to simply use static HTML objects (much as you tried to do with `LiteralControl`), since you don't really need any of the windows UI calls (unless you want to create custom MVC modules to list it to your liking) you're better off just outputting static HTML elements:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "----------------------";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM News;", con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

    int i = 1;
    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string newsArticle = "";

            newsArticle += "<div class='newsBlock'>";
            newsArticle += "    <div class='newsTitle'>" + reader.GetString(1) + "</div>";
            newsArticle += "    <div class='newsData'>" + reader.GetString(2) + "</div>";
            newsArticle += "</div>"

            newsPanel.Controls.add(new LiteralControl(newsArticle));
            i++;
        }
        reader.NextResult();
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

You still need to modify your `index.aspx` to the above tho since the code relies heavily on the object `newsPanel` to be present for populating it with data.